# Duplication after join. I want to bring all contacts of all persons without duplication in records of person table

Tags: mysql

I have tow tables, 1. person 2. contact. both tables have one to many relationship. When I am using join to fetch the records froth both the tables, then record from person table is getting duplicate, as one person may have many contacts. I want to bring all contacts of all persons without duplication in person record

Comment: Your question is a bit thin.  Can you include the schema for both tables along with some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the person data then:

```
select *
from contact
```

If you need the person data then it's not possible to avoid the repetition of the person info for each contact in the join result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.firstname, p.lastname, c.phone
FROM person p INNER JOIN c contact ON p.id = c.id
```